# How to set up MutationObserver to detect added DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, dom, google-chrome-extension

Problem: I want to change some of the default text of Facebook to my own.

I used jQuery's `text()`, but the problem is Facebook will add more DOM when user scrolls down, so I tried to use `MutationObserver` to detect whether there is new DOM coming in.

I tried this in my chrome content_script:

```
// I need to detect new .UFILikeLink elements
var target = document.querySelector('.UFILikeLink');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
    alert('test');
  });    
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

observer.observe(target, config);
```

but this doesn't work, the `alert()` is not firing.. I wonder is this the right way of using `MutationObserver`.

Comment: you want to observe the container where the new content is appended.

Comment: @dandavis can u please explain more?

Comment: Consider changing the question title, it does not fit the question.

Answer (score 3):

The "target" is not a selector for the elements you want to filter, but it should be a single element that represents the root of the subtree you're watching.

For instance, if you want to get notified of all new elements in the body, target should be `document.body`.

If you need to filter results (you presumably do), you should do so in the callback.

*(removed code)*

Since you are already using jQuery, here's a more terse and robust version:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    $(mutation.addedNodes).find(".UFILikeLink").each(function() {
      /* do something */
      console.dir(this); // Note, it's a DOM element, use $(this) if needed        
    });
  });    
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true,  subtree: true });
```

Note that you need the `subtree: true` to watch for mutations deep in the document.

Comment: it seem work, but at this line     mutation.addedNodes.filter(function(node) {
 I got this error : undefined is not a function

Comment: Keep forgetting that various node collections do not have proper array functions. A moment.

Comment: ya I tried it doesn't work.. It shouldn't be so complicated, is mutationobserver is the only way to go?

Comment: It's a bit of a pain doing this without jQuery, honestly. You can also check out [MutationSummary library](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/), it can help. I edited the answer, it will work _now_.

Comment: The question or answer you mean?

Comment: you are awesome! it work.. but is it a must to use forEach? and a for loop within a forEach, that seem will cause the performances issue.

Comment: No, the performance issue is from the observing itself. It is, unfortunately, a strain on the browser. And there is no way to avoid those 3 nested loops, it's how deeply it's buried.

Comment: You can improve performance by taking out config options that you don't need. Like `attributes` and `characterData`.

Comment: var added = mutation.addedNodes[i].getElementsByClassName("UFILikeLink");

this line return undefined is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61099/discussion-between-user3522749-and-xan).